# Reproduce the following flow-chart with smartdiagram in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, smartdiagram

I want to reproduce the following figure with [tikz](/questions/tagged/tikz) and [smartdiagram](/questions/tagged/smartdiagram).
[image]

This is what I got so far [image] using the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
  \node {A}
    child { node {A1} }
    child { node {A2}
      child { node {B1}
        child { node {B2} }
        child { node {C1} } }
      child { node {C2} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any hints.

Comment: You should have a look to the `forest` package which is far more customizable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution with `forest`, which is basically designed to do this kind of thing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={draw, rounded corners=5mm, font=\sffamily,
        minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,
        forked edge, edge={blue,-latex},
        s sep=2cm, l sep=1cm, fork sep=5mm}
    [A[A1][A2[B1[C1][C2]][B2]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @SandyG for introducing me to a wonderful package. Wondering how to increase the width of arrow edges. Thanks

Comment: Just change `edge={blue,-latex, thick}`